# What's the difference between "travel through time", "travel in time"?

Tags: meaning

What's the difference between "travel through time", "travel in time"? I am wondering if both mean the same thing or can be used to mean the same thing as "time travel".

For example:

> He traveled through time to see his dead brother.
>
> He traveled in time to see his dead brother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They’re both essentially the same meaning. However, I would go with “travel through time,” as it indicates more of a movement and is slightly more accurate. Note that with “he traveled in time to see his dead brother,” **in time** also has a nuance of *before it was too late.*

In other words, it could then be said that “he traveled in time to see his dead brother (before they buried him),” or something of the sort. I hope this makes sense.